# git: How to fetch updated code on master to earlier created branch

Tags: git

I am using git for the first time. I created a branch, and I haven't worked on it since then.

I did work in master. Now, I want those changes in my branch too. How can I pull these changes to my branch?

I am using source tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't worked in that branch ever since, you can just do

```
git checkout branchname
git merge master
```

or, the last line can be

```
git rebase master
```

but in this case, both work equally well.

You can see in a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840561/how-do-a-git-rebase-in-sourcetree) thread how to do that in SourceTree.